# c++: non-Ivalue in assignment

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi i would like to make an external single linked list. I have a problem with "Non-Ivalue in assignment" and its occuring on line "this = currP->next" i tried making it currP.next but its also producing an error

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


struct node{
       int data;
       node *next;

       node(int i){
                data = i;
                next = NULL;
                }

       void insert(int position, node &n){
            node *currP = this;
            node *prevP= NULL;      
            for(int counter = 0; counter>=position;counter++, prevP = currP, currP = currP->next){
                    if(counter==position)
                    {
                    n.next  = currP->next;
                    currP->next = &n; 
                                         }                     
                    }

            }

       void add(node &n){
       next = &n;          
                 }
       void deleteNode(int i){
            node *currP = this;
            node *prevP = NULL;

            while(currP!= NULL){
               if(currP->data == i){
                  if(prevP == NULL) 
                      this = currP->next;
                  else{   
                      prevP->next = currP->next;
                  }                      
               }                                                  
               prevP = currP;
               currP = currP->next;
            }
        }
 };
```

Comment: `this` is not a variable. It is a keyword representing the current object. You can not change the current object by trying to set it.

Answer (score 5):

An `lvalue` is a variable that can reside at the left side of the equal operator. This means its value can be changed. You can't change the value of `this`, it's just not permitted, therefore the error.

You could re-write your function as follows:

```
    node* deleteNode(int i){
        if (  this->data == i )
           return this->next;
        else
        {
           if ( this->next )
              this->next = this->next->deleteNode(i);
           else
              return this;
        }
    }
```

`deleteNode()` will now return a pointer to the start of the rest of the list and the recursive algorithm will concatenate the first part with the last part. It's not tested so a few adjustments may be necessary but I hope you get the point.

Comment: To elaborate a little on this answer, instead of assigning to `this`, you could copy the data which for a simple class like this you can do with `*this = *currP->next`. If you don't know what the difference is,  read more about *pointer dereferencing*.

Comment: You might get a more detailed answer on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but in general, I'd question why _removing an item from a list_ was a method of a node at all.

Comment: im trying to make node and list as one struct instead of list and node separated XD..

Comment: @Useless Removing the node might make sense (in which case, the best name for the function isn't `deleteNode`, but `~Node`---the destructor), but his function apparently deletes an arbitrary node further down in the list.  Such a function should be a member of the list class itself, and not of the node.

Comment: @jko - I see that, but I'm suggesting it's a poor seperation of concerns, as @JamesKanze also points out.  It could be reasonable to have a list class with just one member: `node head;` and move the list-management operations into there.  Also: consider how you represent an empty list: is it going to be a NULL node pointer, or a magic _sentinel_ node? ... Anyway, this is rapidly getting too big for a comment.

Answer (score 4):

A lvalue is a semantic rule.
It means "left-value".

Examples of lvalues are:

- A variable. ie "a"
- A memory address. ie "a[4]" or "*(a+8)"

`this` is not a lvalue. You just can't assign anything to it. It's the reference to the method caller.

Comment: how could i make the method caller  variable "next" point to where "currP->next" points?

Comment: `this->next = currP->next;`

You can access `this` like a normal variable, you just can't assign anything to it.